# Reload module if it hasn't been loaded yet in python

Tags: python, module

I'd like to do the following in python:

- check if a module has been imported
- if it hasn't, then import the module using `import module_name`
- if it has, then reload the module using `importlib.reload(module_name)`

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
try:
    importlib.reload(module_name)
except NameError:
    import (module_name)
```

Is there perhaps a better way?

Comment: Unless you are writing a debugger or some other specialized code runner, the best thing to do would be to restart your program if the module has been changed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, if the module name is only available as a string and not loaded beforehand:

```
import importlib
import sys

mod_str = "module_name"

if mod_str in sys.modules:
  mod_obj = importlib.import_module(mod_str)
  importlib.reload(mod_obj)
else:
  mod_obj = importlib.import_module(mod_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get modules imported in your Python script is using **ModuleFinder** (standard Python module).

ModuleFinder class in this module provides *run_script()* and *report()* methods to determine the set of modules imported by a script.

Example:

```
from modulefinder import ModuleFinder
import importlib

finder = ModuleFinder()
finder.run_script('C:/path/your_script.py')

if 'module_name' in finder.modules.keys():
    importlib.reload(module_name)
else:
    importlib.import_module(module_name)
```

NOTE:

Reload and imoprt are previously imported modules. The argument must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before.

Comment: `importlib.reload` doesn't accept string arguments. From the docs "The argument must be a module object, so it must have been successfully imported before"

Comment: @user32882 That it is correct, but I have not mentioned anywhere that module_name should be a string argument. there is obviously a difference between 'module_name' and module_name. but in any case I will write an additional note

Comment: Thanks for the additional note. It turns out I need something where the module has *not* been imported before...